# AttributeError in trying to access a python function

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to access a python function of a class into another script. This gives me the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'functionName'
```

The function is present in a class and is accessed via classname.functionName() call.
Is there anything that I am missing ?

-update-

My code is:

```
(program.py)
import ImageUtils
import ...
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
...
    ImageUtils.ProcessInformation(event)


(ImageUtils.py)
import statements... 
class ImageUtils(threading.Thread):
    def ProcessInformation(self, event):
        self.queue.put(event)
```

Thus, the error is : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ProcessInformation'
So, do I have to make this second script a module only ?

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: Perhaps the code snippet that throws the error? As well as your import statement for the module, since you could have an error in the import step.

Comment: can you please add here more info? like list imports, files tree, etc?

Comment: `function-name` is not a valid identifier. I'm assuming it's just a result of anonymization, but still, it's needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 6):

A function inside a class is called a method. You can access it from another module with

```
import module
module.Classname.method
```

However, unless that method is a special kind of method call a staticmethod or classmethod, 
you won't be able to call it with `module.Classname.method()`.

Instead, you'd need to make an instance of the class:

```
inst=module.Classname(...)
```

and then call the method from the class instance:

```
inst.method()
```

---

The reason you were receiving the error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'function_name'
```

is because `module` does not have a variable named `function_name` in its namespace. It does have a variable named `Classname` however.
Meanwhile, `Classname` has a variable named `function_name` in its namespace. 
So to access the method, you need to "burrow down" to `function_name` by performing two attribute lookups: `module.Classname.function_name`.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to create a static method here, and access it using factory pattern.

Comment: You may be interested in reading http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're trying to call the function from the module instead than from the class. I suggest you to do something like:

```
from my_module import my_class

my_class.my_function(...)
# bla bla bla
```

**EDIT:** I think Python doesn't let you use "-" in a function name.

Comment: you mean my_class.my_function()

Comment: thanks, but as a class is used, this is not possible. I've tried it nevertheless, but that approach fails without a module

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) function to see if the function is actually present as you expect.

Example using the `math` module:

```
>>> import math
>>> dir(math)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', 'acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'atan2', 'ceil', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'hypot', 'ldexp', 'log', 'log10', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh']
```